# No matching signature for operator CASE; ALL THEN/ELSE arguments must be coercible to a common type but found ARRAY<STRING>, STRING;

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting the error mentioned as a question while trying use below logic,

`Select case when T2.val is not null then T2.CD ELSE CASE WHEN T3.VAL <> '~' OR T3.VAL = 'FM' THEN ['F','M'] ELSE T3.VAL END  END AS FVAL FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE3) T3 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TABLE2) T2 ON T2.VAL = T3.VAL;`

NOTE - ALL THE COLUMNS MENTIONED IN ABOVE COLUMN ARE OF STRING DATA TYPE

`Select case when T2.val is not null then T2.CD ELSE CASE WHEN T3.VAL <> '~' OR T3.VAL = 'FM' THEN ['F','M'] ELSE T3.VAL END  END AS FVAL FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE3) T3 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TABLE2) T2 ON T2.VAL = T3.VAL;`

I wanted to populate the value as F,M in FVAL column when the above condition satisfies.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

When using CASE statements in BigQuery, all WHEN/ELSE clauses must have the same result type.

It's hard to tell from your example, since we don't exactly know how TABLE3 looks like, but since you're joining on T2.VAL = T3.VAL, and you have a test for T3.VAL <> '~', we can assume that T2.VAL and T3.VAL are both strings.

Your CASE statement has 3 potential values:

- When T2.VAL is not null (join has a match) - you set the value to be T2.CD, which we can't really tell the type of.
- When T2.VAL is null (join has no match) - and T3.VAL is either 'FM' or any value other than '~', you set the value to be ['F','M'], which is an array.
- When T2.VAL is null (join has no match) - and T3.VAL is '~' - you set the value to be T3.VAL (which is '~' - a string)

Overall, your case statement has at least 2 types of different values set, which is not acceptable in BigQuery, as the table's column type can not be inferred.

Change your logic to make sure that either all values are STRINGs, or all values are ARRAY, but not both.

See more info in the official documentation here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#case

Answer (score 0):

This part: THEN ['F','M']
It returns an array of string, while other parts output string. You need to have a consistent type of output pf either array or string